# How to put n balls into m boxes

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can we put **n** indistinguishable balls into **m** distinguishable boxes, where **m > n**?

Comment: can one box have two or more balls?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707996/number-of-ways-to-distribute-indistinguishable-balls-into-distinguishable-boxes) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441170/number-of-ways-of-distributing-balls-into-boxes).